# Working with large files with a particular extension using directory scan operator

Tags: data-ingestion, ibm-streams

I have a 1GB+ size file coming to my directory from a MQ, this takes some time to completely transfer the file, but a file will be produced in that directory even if it is not a complete one.
I am afraid my directoryScan operator will pick up an incomplete file.
Also, I cannot add an initial delay because I am not sure how much time will it take to transfer the file.

PS: I read somewhere that some of the file transfer protocols take care of this by adding a different extension to the file until it is complete. So say my directoryScan operator is waiting for any file with .txt extension, so this file transfer protocol will create a file with extension .abc until the transfer is complete.

How should I go ahead with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were going to use the regular expression route, here is an example of invoking the operator to only read files of a certain extension:

```
   // DirectoryScan operator with an absolute file argument and a file name pattern         
stream<rstring name> Dir2 = DirectoryScan()                                        
{                                                                                        
  param                                                                                  
    directory : "/tmp/work";                                                             
   pattern : "\\.txt$";                                                                 
}
```

If that doesn't work, is it possible to set up MQ to write the file to a different directory and then move it into your target directory when it is complete?

One thing you could do, if you know the size of the file, is use the `Size()` function to ignore the file until it is the right size.  This snippet uses a `Custom` operator to wait until the file size is at least 2000 bytes.

```
graph
        stream <rstring filename, uint64 size> DirScanOutput = DirectoryScan() {
            param
                directory: "test1";
                sleepTime: 10.0; //wait 10s between scans
                pattern: ".*\\.txt";

          output DirScanOutput : size= Size();
        } 


        stream<rstring file> FileNameStream= Custom(DirScanOutput as In){
            logic
                onTuple In:{
                    if (size < 2000ul){
                        printStringLn("Required size not met yet.");
                    } else {
                        printStringLn("Size of file reached.");
                        submit({file=filename}, FileNameStream);

                    }
                }
        }

        stream <cityData> CityDataRecord = FileSource(FileNameStream) {
            param
                format: csv;
        }
```

I hope one of these suggestions works for you.

Comment: Will the regular expression method wait for the file transfer to complete or will it spick up the incomplete file as soon as it gets created? I am of the view that it will pick up the incomplete file, so this method won't work.

Also, I don't know the exact size of the file and it might change from time to time, so can't put a check on the size.

Comment: I think the only other thing to do is to see if you can move the file into the target directory when it is finished downloading. Or, perhaps you can stream the data directly into Streams? Does it have to go from the MQ server to a file before going into Streams?  Have you thought of using one of the operators in the messaging toolkit? http://ibmstreams.github.io/streamsx.messaging/